# Is possible to decline all old access tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am developing an android mobile client and signing with oauth2 to our server that is written in c#. Everything is working well, until the server is rebooting.

I'm crashing every call to the server.. at first I've thought that my access token is not valid anymore. but after I've decided to have my own local server I saw that my calls do reach the server and they crash inside because of some static lists of tokens and user data that the server team developed and obviously getting cleared after restarting the server.

I've told them to recreate their lists of data and access tokens, but no luck for me there..

My question, 
I'm not so good in server-side and oauth2 developing but i'm pretty sure there is a solution for what i want. I've tried searching for few hours without success. My thought is - To make the server decline all old access tokens from previous run of the server - and i will get unauthorised code in my client (Now i'm getting just crush in server that i don't know why and how to react in my app) Something like - Each time the server restart it will have a random seed and will create its access tokens with this seed.

Is there something like this ? or some other "Not so much work" solution for the lazy server-side team :)?

Answer (score 0):

The service that is issuing you the OAuth token is also the service that needs to revoke tokens. There is nothing inside a token that you can change to invalidate it that would also not corrupt it.

If your server is crashing because you are sending it unknown / invalid tokens, this is a serious problem. The first step than anyone will do (should do) is to validate the token. Evidentally they are not. Security requires attention to detail and having a server crash due to tokens is a security problem (Denial of Service).

Comment: The server is crashing just because it saves list with tokens before its restart. so the client token is still valid but the lists in the server are empty so they crash. The request past to the server (valid token) so it must be in the list (At least this was their thought).. Anyway, to bad there is no trick here but telling them to handle all the places that the token does not exist in their lists